# How do noise-canceling headphones cancel out white noise, which is unpredictable in nature?

Tags: noise-cancellation

From what I know noise-canceling headphones generate sound waves that are 180° out of phase with the ambient noise. I understand that they are not effective at canceling out sudden and unpredictable sounds, such as a car horn or a dog barking, because there isn't enough time for them to process the sound and generate the phase-inverted wave, and they are generally good at canceling out periodic sounds because it's easier to predict the sound wave and generate the inverted wave on time. What is confusing to me, however, is that they are also very effective in canceling out white noise, which is by definition random and unpredictable. Some sources say that this is because it is sustained and has a well-defined frequency spectrum. But that doesn't make sense to me because even if we perfectly know the frequencies if the phase is random there would be no way to generate the inverted wave, unless it's done instantaneously, which would make them able to cancel out any kind of sudden sound. What am I missing here?

Comment: Most cheap "noise canceling" headsets don't actually cancel anything by generating anti-phase sound waves, most cheap headsets just generate a baseline white noise and it just makes it harder for your ear to detect sounds that are already attenuated by the closed structure of the headset.

Comment: @Justme: that would be "noise masking" not "noise cancellation". I don't think any of my headsets/phones that I owned ever did that. It would also never be "white". Pink or brown would be much better choice.

Comment: @Hilmar That is what the marketing departments just print on the product even if it really uses noise masking.

Answer (score 4):

They measure the noise and deploy a feedback loop.

Most "better" noise cancelling headsets these days are so-called "hybrids" and deploy three different mechanisms.

**Feed-forward** : There is a microphone on the outside of the headset or earphone that measures the incoming sound. The manufacturer carefully characters the transfer function from that microphone to the entrance of the ear canal, applies that transfer function to the microphone signal, multiplies it with -1 and feeds it to the driver.

**Feedback** : There is another microphone(s) inside the headset, as close to the ear canal as possible (sometimes it's even inside). The headset implements a control loop to drive that signal to 0. In simple terms, it takes the microphone signal, corrects for the transfer function of the driver, multiplies it with -1, applies some loop dynamics and plays it back to the driver. That's the part that occasionally can produce "howling", i.e. acoustic feedback.

**Passive Attenuation**: That's just regulars acoustics which works by passively blocking as much sounds as possible. This is more complicated than it sounds as it requires careful trade-off between air tightness, clamping force, person-person variability, comfort, etc.

All three mechanisms have there strengths and weaknesses so a well designed headset  carefully tunes all three with respect to each other and for the overall experience. It's come a long way: a really well designed noise cancelling headset the incoming sound energy by a factor of 1000 or so over a fairly wide frequency range and still be comfortable to wear all the way from New York to Hong Kong (16 hour flight).

Comment: Nice summary. I think it is worthwhile to point out that while these headphones can actively cancel low to mid frequency noise (and passively block out mid to high frequencies), they tend to add some noise in the mid frequencies of their own. Evidently, this is tied to the latency of the control loop. In noisy environments that may not be an issue, but in quiet environments that is an annoying feature of my Sony headphones.

Comment: Hm, maybe something is wrong with your headset? A friend of mine measured some of the newer Sony's and nothing like that showed up. I tried that casually and thought they worked quite well and I certainly didn't hear any elevated noise levels in the mid range

Answer (score 1):

To add to Hilmar’a excellent summary of noise cancellation techniques, I believe the OP’s core confusion lies in the frequency domain characteristics of noise and how something that is randomly generated can be cancelled, and especially how that relates to the “loop bandwidth” of the noise cancellation.

The loop bandwidth is the maximum rate at which the cancellation loop can track and offer some cancellation to the disturbance; slowly changing disturbances that have frequency content far below the loop bandwidth are easy to track by the faster loop and readily cancelled, but disturbances that change faster than the loop bandwidth will not be able to be tracked. If the loop bandwidth is above our audible hearing range, then we can achieve cancellation of the randomly generated signals within our hearing.

Consider in general how a low frequency signal changes slowly and thus we can readily predict what the immediate subsequent values will be even if randomly generated. A “sudden” variation is in itself a high frequency signal and not as easy to track. “White Noise” has content at all frequencies and noise cancellation loops act as high pass filters to this random noise.